# FluentValidation not using my Rules

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, autofac, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation with Autofac and ValidatorFactoryBase

When I execute my project my Validator is executed, but when I send a post my rules not is used but the current validator is my own Validator.

My Validator:

```
public class UsuarioCadastrarValidator : AbstractValidator<UsuarioCadastrarVM>
{
    public UsuarioCadastrarValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Nome).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Campo obrigatório");

        RuleFor(a => a.Nome).Length(4, 200).WithMessage("Digite seu nome completo");
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
public class UsuarioCadastrarVM
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int CargoId { get; set; }
}
```

Global.asax(Works well):

```
...
    FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();


            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                   .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Validator"))
                   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                   .InstancePerLifetimeScope();


            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly);

            builder
            .RegisterType<FluentValidation.Mvc.FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider>()
            .As<ModelValidatorProvider>();

            builder.RegisterType<AutofacValidatorFactory>().As<IValidatorFactory>().SingleInstance();

            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
...
```

Controller(Works well):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cadastrar(UsuarioCadastrarVM vm)
{
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
      {

      }
}
```

My ValidatorFactoryBase (Works well):

```
public class AutofacValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _context;

    public AutofacValidatorFactory(IComponentContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        object instance;
        if (_context.TryResolve(validatorType, out instance))
        {
            var validator = instance as IValidator;
            return validator;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When I send Post with "Nome" and "CargoId" empty in ModelState has only one message "CargoId is required" and not exists that Rule, I think is because CargoId is a integer.

But, Why my Rules are not consider?

Comment: Based [on the documentation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/h.-MVC), by default, it will only wire up validators by looking at the `ValidatorAttribute` on the model that is being validated.  You don't seem to have one, nor do you seem to be passing in a custom `ValidatorFactory` setting.

Comment: debugging my ValidatorFactoryBase return the correct Validator and watching ModelState the current validator is the correct.

Comment: Also, what is `ViewModelValidator`?

Comment: I edited, `ViewModelValidator` is a abstract class where have methods to help, not is relevant

Comment: I created a new project with autofac, fluentvalidation, and related mvc integrations, pasted your code in, set up a new view etc. and the code is working as you expect it (I get the correct messages in `ModelState`).  Could it be that something you removed to simplify the example is causing the issue?

Comment: maybe, the only one thing I removed was the inheritance of AbstractValidator, but not have constructor or create Rules, is only to get instance of database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `CargoId` is a integer, so the `MVC` is not able to bind my post to my ViewModel, because in my tests I sended a empty value, if I send a value to `CargoId` or change to nullable (`int?`) the validation works well.